# Alternate image doesn't display error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a recordset called $row_try['picture'].

When the recordset is empty or column is null, I have an if statement to display an alternative image which I have in my image folder with path: images/default.jpg.

#### Issue:

It doesn't give me an error, nor does it work either. It just shows blank.

#### Code:

```
        *<td width="123">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="600"><?php if(!empty($row_try['picture'])){ 'images/default.jpg'?> <img src="picture/<?php echo $row_try['picture']; ?>" alt="" width="600" height="300"/><?php } // Show if recordset not empty ?>
    </td>*
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    mysql_free_result($try);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution...

```
<td width="24">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="857"><?php if($row_try['picture'] == "") echo"<img src='picture/prepup.jpg'"; {  ?> <img src="picture/<?php echo $row_try['picture']; ?>" width="600" height="300"/><?php }  ?> &nbsp;</td>
```